# C# deserialize JSON String to Object

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to build an app to retrieve certain information from Azure. I started with the tenants info to test, but I have an issue deserializing a JSON String to an object. I look through several examples and I could not let them work. Could you guide me if I am writing wrogly the Object or is there any issue with the JSON String?

```
public class JSONValues
{
    IEnumerable<TenantDTO> value { get; set; }
}
public class TenantDTO
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string tenantId { get; set; }
    public string countryCode { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string tenantCategory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<String> domains { get; set; }
}
```

To read the JSON I use:

```
var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JSONValues>(strJSON);
```

where strJSON is:

```
   {
    "value": [{
            "id": "/tenants/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "tenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "countryCode": "US",
            "displayName": "xxxxx",
            "domains": ["xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com", ...., "tenantCategory": "Home"
            }]
    }
```

but didn't work either.

Comment: It would help if you pasted Valid JSON, otherwise it is difficult to debug the problem

Comment: Your json is not correct (or your class). `tenantCategory` is part of the `domains`array in your json

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ is your friend in this case.

Comment: Care to elaborate - but didn't work either ? is there an exception or just that some property isn't getting deserialized correctly, what is it ?

Comment: All properties must be `public` to be accessed be serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `public` as access specifier for `value` property

```
public class JSONValues
{
    public IEnumerable<TenantDTO> value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank I didn't notice that the visibility was not set to public.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the class definition for the object, the deserialization will fail.

To test your stuff, first *write* a json, then Deserialize again:

```cs
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new JSONValues() );
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONValues>( json );
```